# Inverse Function Theorem and finding local inverses

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-topology

$f(x,y) = (x+y,x^2+y)$  for this function, the question  is Write down a $C^1$
local inverse around (0, 0).  
I wonder how can I find the points f has a local inverse? I am trying to use Lagrange multipliers but I am confused, and also how can I understand it does not have a local inverse for any point for example (1/2,0). 
I am a new learner for this topic and some notions are really interesting for me, and this type of question is hard to think for me.

Comment: It has a local inverse where the Jacobian is nonsingular. The Jacobian is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2x & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ so it is nonsingular as long as $2x \neq 1$ i.e. $x \neq 1/2$. Lagrange multipliers has nothing to do with it.

Comment: As for finding it, you solve the equations $x+y=x',x^2+y=y'$ (which can be done with just simple algebra, but two solutions are obtained). You choose the solution with the property that when you put in $f(0,0)=(0,0)$, you obtain $(0,0)$ back. Only one of the solutions has this property.

Comment: @Ian I've been working on this problem for a bit to try to refresh my memory of multivariable analysis.  I thought we needed to solve the differential equation which came from the inverse matrix of the Jacobian,  not the Jacobian?

Comment: @Alan In your answer you described how to find the Jacobian of the inverse. The question in the OP is to actually find the inverse itself.

Comment: @Ian Yes, I was continuing on from that by trying to use the Jacobian of the inverse to set up the system of differential equations.  Going to post what I had in so you can see, will clean up answer+comments here after!

Comment: @Alan You can just find the inverse explicitly with algebra, there is no need to use calculus to find it in this simple case.

Answer (score 2):

We have the theorem: Let $f$ is a function from open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $f$ is of class $C^r$. If $Df(x)$ (the derivative) is non-singular at the point $\textbf{a}$ of $A$, then there is a neighborhood $U$ of the point $\textbf{a}$ such that $f$ is one-to-one from $U$ to an open set $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (hence the inverse function exists), and the  inverse function is of class $C^{r}$.

So to determine that $f$ has local inverse in your question, it is sufficient to check the singularity of the $Df$ at the given point.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse is a mapping from $(u,v)$ to $(x,y)$, with $g(u,v)=(x,y)$, so that

$$x+y=u \\
x^2+y=v.$$

This system can be solved algebraically, but there are two solutions unless $u-v \geq 1/4$:

$$x^2+y-(x+y)=v-u \\
x=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1-4(u-v)}}{2} \\
y=u-x=\frac{2u-1 \mp \sqrt{1-4(u-v)}}{2}.$$

However, because $f(0,0)=(0,0)$, you want $g(0,0)=(0,0)$. Only one of these two mappings has this property.